# Referencing a database entry within an image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails.

I've made a blog, and loaded a few entries include title, content and image (which is a string detailing the path of the image).

I've had a search around and can't find a solution - I was just wondering whether there is a way that I can reference the data within the image field in an image_tag, so that the image field links to the relevent image?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide an example as to what you need to be done and/or sample code? :)

Comment: I've created a backend for my site (which is on the basis a portfolio website) using RoR. This is so that I can power a blog through my website and publish entries throughout my website.

Each blog entry is made up of a title, content and an image. The image field I figured would be best suited as a String which relates to the path in which the image lives in my folders.
I would like to display the relevant image using the data entry within the image field... is this possible using data within a database entry?

Comment: i would suggest that you use the paperclip gem instead of storing the images in your folders. it makes everything easier (for others, they prefer carrierwave, so whichever floats your boat) :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but for now this would be a distraction from the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming You can use the following:

```
<%= image_tag blogentry.image, :alt => 'Whatever' %>
```

This supposes a few things:

- your images are store in /app/public/images or /app/assets/images
- your model is called `blogentry` (change accordingly)
- your `image` field contains the relative path from the public/images (or assets/images) folder
- your ìmage` field also contains the file name and extension

and if the path is always the same, you can do the following

```
<%= image_tag "path/to/your/image/#{blogentry.image}", :alt => 'Whatever' %>
```

in this example, the path to your images would be `app/public/images/path/to/your/image/` (or app/assets/images/...).

This also assumes your field contains the name and the extension.

Comment: This works perfectly. Previously I was using "" around the post.image.

Is there a way I could prefix the path which appears before each image, so that at the data entry stage I would have to type JUST the file name?